# Laravel 3 way pivot table with array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello I have these columns participant_id, choice_id and question_id in `participant_choice_question` table. What I want to achieve is to attach also the question_id to a table row.

```
participant_id|choice_id |question_id
--------------|----------|-----------
     1        |        1 |      4
     1        |        2 |      5
     1        |        3 |      6
```

However, I got error **"Array to string conversion"** this is because of the 2 parameter "`['question_id' => $question_ids]`" in my controller.

Please see controller below.

```
foreach ($request->questions as $question => $question_value) {                  
   question_ids[] = $question_value;
}

foreach ($request->choices as $choice => $choice_value) {
   $choices =  $participant->choices()->attach($choice_value, ['question_id' => $question_ids]);
}
```

Comment: Please add your relationship models, and how are your tables arranged. Add more details to your question

Answer (score 1):

To store an array in a database column using Laravel, you can use the json data type

```
    $table->json('question_id');
```

In your model, you should define the $casts property to indicate that the column should be treated as an array:

```
 protected $casts = [
    'question_id' => 'array',
    ];
```